# How to prove statement regarding directional derivatives and gradients

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

The question asked me to prove that

$$\|\nabla f\|^2 = (D_{u}f)^2 + (D_{v}f)^2$$

whenever vectors $u$ and $v$ are perpendicular.

How can I prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$\Vert \nabla f \Vert^2=(\nabla f\boldsymbol{\cdot}\underline{u})^2+(\nabla f \boldsymbol{\cdot}\underline{v})^2$$
Let $\theta$ and $\phi$ be the angles between $\nabla f$ and $\underline{u},\underline{v}$ respectively. Then $$(\nabla f \boldsymbol{\cdot}\underline{u})^2=\Vert \nabla f \Vert^2\Vert\underline{u}\Vert^2 \cos^2(\theta)$$ and $$(\nabla f \boldsymbol{\cdot}\underline{v})^2=\Vert \nabla f \Vert^2\Vert\underline{v}\Vert^2 \cos^2(\phi)$$
Perhaps you can take it from here?

**EDIT:** It's only true if the two vectors are *orthonormal*, not orthogonal. I.e $\Vert \underline{u} \Vert=
\Vert \underline{v} \Vert =1$.
Continuing on,
$$1=\Vert \underline{u}\Vert^2 \cos^2(\theta) + \Vert \underline{v} \Vert^2 \cos^2(\phi)$$
Since $\underline{u}$ and $\underline{v}$ are orthogonal, $\phi = \theta \pm \pi/2$. WLOG, I'll assume $\phi = \theta + \pi/2$. But, as $\cos^2(x+\pi/2)=1-\cos^2(x)=\sin^2(x)$ (check this),
$$1=\Vert \underline{u}\Vert^2 \cos^2(\theta)+  \Vert \underline{v} \Vert^2 \sin^2(\theta)$$
Which is obviously true as long as $\Vert \underline{u} \Vert=
\Vert \underline{v} \Vert =1.$

Comment: Actually, I was struggling because I only can reach until here. Do you mind telling me the next step needed to prove this?

Comment: This is why it helps to show some of your own workings when asking questions. Nevertheless, I'll edit my question.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm new to this site. I'll be more careful next time :(

Comment: @Ca Ching Upon further inspection I've noticed that the vectors need not only be orthogonal but *orthonormal* as well.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I really appreciate it.

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, you can mark it as "accepted" by hitting the green check mark :)